# What is the reason to specify ':cANSI' (or another character set) for a font

Tags: vimrc, vim-windows

I often see that fonts intended to be used on Windows are defined with `:cANSI`.

```
set guifont=Consolas:h11:cANSI
```

The help is, of course, provide some explanation, but I don't really understand it.

> cXX - character set XX.  Valid charsets are: ANSI, ARABIC, BALTIC, CHINESEBIG5, DEFAULT, EASTEUROPE, GB2312, GREEK, HANGEUL, HEBREW, JOHAB, MAC, OEM, RUSSIAN, SHIFTJIS, SYMBOL, THAI, TURKISH and VIETNAMESE.  Normally you would use "cDEFAULT".

> **Examples:**
>
> - `:set guifont=courier_new:h12:w5:b:cRUSSIAN`
> - `:set guifont=Andale_Mono:h7.5:w4.5`

Here is my vimrc:

```
if has('multi_byte')
  if &encoding !~? '^u'
    if &termencoding == ''
      let &termencoding = &encoding
    endif
    set encoding=utf-8
  endif
  setglobal fileencoding=utf-8
  set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,cp1251,latin1
endif

" set guifont=Consolas:h11:cANSI
" set guifont=Consolas:h11
" set guifont=Consolas:h11:cRUSSIAN
```

I can use `:h11:cANSI`, just `:h11`, or `:h11:cRUSSIAN`, and I don't see any difference.

What is the reason to use `:cANSI` or `:cRUSSIAN`? Maybe this is something that was necessary in older versions of Vim only?

Comment: Charsets are not used with Unicode.

Comment: @Matt Well, I expected something like this. But could you show or describe a case where their use is required? Using `set guifont=Consolas:h11:cRUSSIAN` with a clean vimrc, for example, doesn't provide a possibity to see Russian characters, such as д or ф.

Comment: I think the charset is more or less vaguely explained by microsoft here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/character-sets-used-by-fonts

Comment: @jsv Charset is only needed if `&encoding` is not Unicode one. For example, until very late Vim for Windows used default charset (i.e. `set enc=cp1251` for Russian locale). Then cRUSSIAN charset for `guifont` will be required.

Comment: @Matt I just tested `set encoding=cp1251 guifont=Consolas:h11` with Vim 8.2.2824 and this works perfectly fine even without charset. (Thanks anyway.)

Comment: I also see that Russians often use `:cRUSSIAN::` instead of `:cRUSSIAN`, and I don't see explanation for these `::` in `:help`.

Comment: @user90726 I believe each `:` is simply the separator vim uses between options. So `::` specifies two "blank" options that are ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically "Charset" denoted a set of glyphs used for the codes 128-255 (i.e. 1-byte chars except those standartized by ASCII 0-127). Now with Unicode everywhere it is of little value and use.

If you need an illustrative example, here it is

1. Running GVim 9 on Windows 11 Russian. Everything looks right for the default font.

```
> gvim --cmd "set enc=cp1251" --clean
```

[image: GVim #1]

2. Set new font and show intro again. What's this?!

```
set guifont=Consolas
intro
```

[image: GVim #2]

3. Force cRUSSIAN charset and it's back!

```
set guifont=Consolas:cRUSSIAN
intro
```

[image: GVim #3]

Of course, if `&encoding` is UTF-8 then all this stuff does just nothing.

Comment: I have recently made fonts (nerdfonts) that seem to have `cANSI` in the font name string, on Windows. Are there any others that are still in use?

Comment: @paradroid Encoding is not "a font feature" but rather "a parameter request". So I cannot make sense out of your question.

Comment: I've made a gvim plugin which changes font size using key mappings or mousewheel. I've covered `qDRAFT`, `b`, `Wxxx` and `cANSI` in the regex to match any possible attributes in the font string, but I am not sure if there could be any others that I haven't encountered.